# How to calculate Accuracy for Scene Text Detection method?

Tags: python, math, image-processing, text, detection

I'm studying about Scene Text Detection and recognition method. After applying my method to a image, I have a image result (attached image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyrwq.png). So, if I want to calculate Accuracy in image result follow formula: ( TP + TN ) / ( TP + TN + FP + FN ), how should I do ? I read about Confusion matrix but I don't know how to apply it to image result.
Thanks for reading <3

Comment: such accuracy is usually evaluated as "intersection over union". one could reformulate that in terms of *pixels* that are TP/TN/FP/FN. -- let me say "marked" for any pixel that's in a bounding box and labeled correctly of course -- FP is any "detected"/marked pixel that shouldn't, and FN is any pixel that isn't marked but should be. if a pixel is marked as one thing when it should be another, that also counts as false.

Comment: Hi @ChristophRackwitz, thank you so much for explaining it so clearly. But can you answer another question ? I don't understand what TN is in this case. I don't see you mention TN in your answer, is it always equals to 0 ?

Comment: TN = true negatives. It woud be non marked pixels which are correct.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.